# How to custom select an intercept and re-arrange order of model output in R?

Tags: r, output, linear-regression

I'm looking to select my intercept to be StateType_Control and to re-order the output to be preboat, boat, post boat, pre multi boat, multi boat, post multi boat for my linear regression model output in R (See output below)

```
lm(formula = Whistle ~ State_Type, data = M_Behav)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.1092 -0.0474 -0.0474 -0.0363 14.8990 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              0.03630    0.01048   3.463 0.000536 ***
State_Typecontrol        0.01107    0.01317   0.841 0.400524    
State_Typemultiboat     -0.01644    0.01697  -0.969 0.332625    
State_Typepostboat       0.06465    0.01822   3.549 0.000389 ***
State_Typepostmultiboat -0.03630    0.03326  -1.092 0.275016    
State_Typepreboat        0.07291    0.01820   4.006 6.22e-05 ***
State_Typepremultiboat  -0.02776    0.03326  -0.835 0.403942
```